# Calling method from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, object, methods

To begin, I would like to apologize for my English :)

I have FirstViewController, which contains scrollView. This is scrolView with enabled paging, and have 2 pages with 2 different view controllers. From one of the view controllers by touching the button the third view controller appears like a modal view. I call a method in FirstViewController that must disable scrolling and hide two labels which is not contained in the scrollView.
Method is executing, but UI not changes, scrolling still enabled and labels still visible.

Now a bit of code:

This is a piece of the FirstViewController.h (not the whole code):

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label2;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;

-(void)prepareToModal;


@end
```

Now it's `-(void)prepareToModal;` implementation:

```
-(void)prepareToModal {
    [label1 setHidden:YES];
    [label2 setHidden:YES];
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

So, from the one of the view controllers, which contained in scrollView, I call `prepareToModal`

Previously:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
```

Next:

```
FirstViewController *vc = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
[vc prepareToModal];
[vc release];
```

So, that's all. I put a breakpoint in prepareToModal, and it stopped executing. The method is called, but nothing changes on screen...

What am I doing wrong?
How to do this correctly?

**Update**:

I solved this problem.

When I present this modal view, I wrote this:

```
ThirdViewController *tvc = [[ThirdViewControler alloc] init];
tvc.delegate  = self;

UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tvc];

[self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];

[tvc release];
[nc release];
```

Now, insted of `[self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];` I write this:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
```

And It's working very well, I don't need a method `-(void)prepareToModal;`

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have hooked up your IBOutlets in Interface Builder.

Comment: You aren't actually doing anything with VC in that example, so it can't be the one that is showing on the screen!?! You simply create a NEW instance of one, call the prepare modal method and release it....

Comment: If you already have an instance of FirstViewController showing (the one that is displaying the scrollview and labels) then you need to call the prepare method on THAT not on a new instance. I can't see enough of you code to give you specifics.... BUT if you are using a standard setup then in the app delegate is where your FirstViewController instance will be....